# What does it mean when components in schematics do not connect?

Tags: arduino, integrated-circuit, schematics, breadboard, sd

I'm fairly new to the whole Arduino world, and I'm just really curious about this schematic that I came across... I can read the basics of a schematic, but this one has me puzzled. What are the integrated circuits down at the bottom that aren't connected to anything?

How do you know where they go in the circuit? [image: This is the schematic for the Adafruit MicroSD breakout board.]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

IC1 has six sections (A-F) although only 4 are used the circuit.

In general it is not allowed to leave inputs of CMOS devices unconnected so the two at the bottom show what to do with the inputs, connect them to ground. Section E also shows how the connections for the power supply pins of the entire device.  The outputs are not used and so are shown as unconnected.

If you did leave the inputs of sections E and F unconnected they could cause incorrect operation of the sections that are used (A-D).

kevin

Comment: so the number listed in the inputs in outputs of those buffers is which pin they correspond to?

Comment: @nfoggia: Correct.

Comment: okay, just one last question, so IC1a-f aren't actual components, they are simply inside of IC1?

Comment: Actually, it's not section E, it's section P, which happens to be placed right on top of section E.

Comment: @nfoggia: Also correct. Letters (usually lowercase) after the numeric segment refer to subcircuits of the device.

Answer (score 7):

The nets that are named 'CLK', 'DO', etc. are connected, just the wires aren't drawn for the sake of clarity.  Now, IC1E and IC1F that are not connected to anything are unused portions of IC1, which is a hex buffer chip.  One chip gives you 6 independent buffers, but in this case only 4 of them are used, so the last two have their input grounded and output floating to prevent excessive power consumption.  This is often seen when using ICs with multiple independent units - dual or quad op amps, discrete flip flops and CMOS switches, etc.  There are some guidelines about how you are supposed to connect these unused units so that they will not consume excessive power, oscillate and produce noise, or damage themselves.  Generally the idea is to tie inputs off somewhere (Vcc/Vdd or GND) and leave outputs floating.  For things like op amps, buffering virtual ground is the safest solution (output to inverting input, noninverting input to power rail center - either 0v for a bipolar supply or Vdd/2 for a unipolar supply).

For reference, IC1 is a 4050 hex buffer with the following pinout:

[image: 4050]

As you can see, there are 6 individual buffers inside that all share one pair of power pins.  Most logic chips come in 14 or 16 pin packages, which leave 12 or 14 pins available for the logic elements after accounting for the power pins.  These divide nicely into 6 buffers or inverters (2x6 = 12 pins) or 4 2-input AND, OR, XOR, etc. logic gates (3x4 = 12 pins).

Comment: So is IC1d connected to IC1A or 'CLK' or both?

Comment: The net called CLK contains pins JP1 pin 4, IC1 pin 3, and IC1 pin 9.